# (Curious) - Better to have a top-level smart component or small connected components?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I have built some larger Redux apps in the past (it's so much fun) but now I am using it to build a simple small single splash page type of thing. I chose Redux because there is some state/UI actions to manage that I think suit it well. Plus it's awesome.

As it is now, I have the top-level `<App />` component as the only component connected to the store/able to dispatch actions (via `mapStateToProps/mapDispatchToProps` methods), and each of it's decedents/section components are essentially "dumb components" that just keep passing down parts of the state and action dispatch functions.

I could see myself writing this in another way where each section/component/major descendant connects to the store separately. I like the idea of this because there would be less passing down props to many descendants, but the "trickle down" method expressed above reminds me more of the data-flow for the first few React apps I wrote.

I am just curious what the consensus was on the best way to go about this, or if there even is one or is it totally up to me as the developer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem with only one connected component at the very top level of your apps is that you have to explicitly pass down props to child component, sometimes you end up passing down property and callback through child of child of child, etc. Many of your components will receive props from their parent just to pass them down to their children, without using them. When you see yourself in such situation, it's a good indication that you should consider creating a connected component instead as Dan Abramov stated :

> You are coupling parent components too hard to what child components need to render. You're essentially passing many props that are only required by children, and changing them can involve painful refactorings. Instead, as soon as you see that component passes props down without using it, we suggest generating a "container" component using connect().

[source](https://github.com/reactjs/redux/issues/1176#issuecomment-167015145)

Furthmore, with only a top-level connected component your app will always re-render from the very top to the bottom. Even with rigorous `shouldComponentUpdate` implementation on every of your dumb components, you will hit bad performance.

Take a look to [the discussion from where I excerpted this quote](https://github.com/reactjs/redux/issues/1176)

Comment: Thank you for your response! Do you have any other info/articles about improving performance in React?

Comment: I've got a whole bunch of articles on React and Redux performance over at https://github.com/markerikson/react-redux-links/blob/master/react-performance.md.  Some very useful information in those links.

Comment: Hero status, thanks man!

Answer (score 4):

***small connected components*** cause it reduces on unnecessary re-renders each part of the app updates its own state.
good solution: REACT CONF https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KYzlpRvWZ6c.

Comment: Thanks for your response!

Comment: Thanks for youtube link